# Science fiction book where humans now live on a space ark and have lost the coordinates to Earth

Tags: story-identification, books, powers

I remember reading this one book in 2014. The title had the protagonist's name in it. The story is set in the future where humans are now living on a space ark and have left planet Earth behind. Well technically, they lost the coordinates to Earth so they can't go back anymore.

I can't really remember the storyline but, the protagonist was a boy who was living on the space ark. The boy started having these strange dreams where he would be on Earth as a different person. I can't remember if he could tell if it was Earth or not. In the "dreams" that he had, he had powers? I think he later finds out that he was traveling back in time and living as a totally different person. I think as the story develops, the two different lives that he is living start to intertwine with each other and he finds out stuff about the space ark.

I'm not 100% sure about the information I've provided. The only parts that I'm 100% sure about is the fact that humans are now living on a space ark, they've lost the coordinates to Earth, the boy starts to experience two different lives; one as a boy on the ark and the other as a boy on Earth with powers. An extra piece of information that I'm not sure of is that people on Earth all have powers and the social hierarchy is based on the powers that you have. I think the people that are behind humanity's demise want the history of Earth gone. That includes the fact that humans actually possess powers.

I also remember another character. It was the boy’s professor or teacher in the space ark. I think I remember him being good and he owned a library if I remember correctly or he was the librarian. And just like everyone else, he also didn't know much about the history of Earth and how humans ended up on the space ark but he was very much fascinated about it. This has been eating at me for years now but I can't seem to find the book.

I don't know how accurate this is but if I remember correctly, the cover of the book was of the protagonist's silhouette illuminated in some kind of light. The title of the book goes something along the lines of this, "[protagonist's name] the boy with supernatural powers" or the boy who was chosen. It sounds similar to that but I can't remember.

Comment: Hi there. That's a very detailed question, maybe you might add whether you read it in English/other, if it was a translation, or any recollection of the cover?

Comment: I don't think it was a translation and the cover is very hazy in my mind. I think it was the silhouette of the protagonist illuminated in light.

Answer (score -1):

You might look up [*Orphans of the Sky*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphans_of_the_Sky) (1963) by Robert Heinlein. This one has a similar story line to what you describe. What is missing are the "powers" and the two identities.

It is however about a Space Ark traveling to Far Centauri and it was so long a trip the inhabitants almost forgot they were on a spaceship. No one had seen the Control Room for eons on end until one young man gets curious and start exploring the forbidden levels.

Comment: I never like to see _Orphans of the Sky_ mentioned without a reminder that it's based on Heinlein's iconic novella "[Universe](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7992983-universe)".

Comment: It's a space ark story (lots of those, Heinlein's wasn't even the first), and the protagonist is a boy. Otherwise, the OP'sdescription seems to have nothing in common with Heinlein's story.

Comment: @Spencer I read "Universe" 6 or 7 decades ago. Never got around to reading the sequel "Common Sense" or the novel "Orphans of the Sky". Am I missing something great?

Comment: @user11411 I read "Common Sense" but I don't remember anything from it. That may be your answer. Anyway, the problem is that Wikipedia redirects "Universe" to _OOTS_.

Comment: @user14111 Common Sense isn't very good or memorable, and that's from a diehard early Heinlein fan. Orphans is just a fix-up of the two stories.

Comment: @Spencer The wikipedia page considers "Universe" to be _part of_ OOTS.  Is that a mistake?

Comment: @Spencer Yes, but OOTS _includes_ Universe, it's not _based on_ it from what everything seems to suggest.  There's a pretty big difference between the two.  It's not like it's changed from Universe, it's Universe and a second story put together.

Comment: @Spencer Common Sense was written in 1941. http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46441